# How to use autofocus cursor in ionic popup

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, popup

I have a popup with an input type in which I would like to add the autofocus option. I have created a directive for the  autofocus which works fine in labels but when I use the same in popup input type it is not working. Even I have set the focus-me equals true in input  but even it didn't work in popup. Can anyone tell me how to use  the autofocus in popup?

Directive:

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
return {
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  $timeout(function() {
    element[0].focus(); 
  });
}
};
});
```

Popup:

```
function showPopup () {
  $scope.data = {};
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input focus-Me type="text" ng-model="data.expensetype" limit-char limit="15">',
    title: $translate.instant('{{"penterexpensetype_message" | translate}}'),
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
     { text: $translate.instant('{{"pcancel_message" | translate}}') },
      {
        text: $translate.instant('{{"psave_message" | translate}}'),
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function (e) {
          if (!$scope.data.expensetype) {
            //don't allow the user to close unless he enters producttype
            e.preventDefault();

          } else {
            addExpenseCategory();
            return $scope.data.expensetype;
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function (res) {
    $log.log('Tapped!', res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correct directive name in uppercase and lowercase

```
template: '<input focus-me type="text" ng-model="data.expensetype" limit-char limit="15">'
```